# AzureReader2 with ImageResizer prefix issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, imageresizer

We are using AzureReader2 plugin to read the blob urls and ImageResizer plugin to re-size images on fly.

Our container name is - img

AzureReader2 prefix name is also - img

```
<add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/img/" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=my;AccountKey=my endpoint="http://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/" />
```

So, the image url is looking like below:

http://.blob.core.windows.net/img/img/1GKS2EEF2BR171185/f81c8448-47cb-4448-b1d3-d59a07394bb4.jpg?w=500

img is repeated twice.

Is there any way to handle this?

Can we use empty prefix with ImageResizer?

Any advise is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example URL you've provided, I think you are misunderstanding the  process. [The cloud architecture page](http://imageresizing.net/docs/cloud) can be helpful here.

[image: Cloud diagram]

Your image URL should not be `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/img/img/1GKS2EEF2BR171185/f81c8448-47cb-4448-b1d3-d59a07394bb4.jpg?w=500`

Without a CDN, it should be in the form `http://myserverwithimageresizer.com/img/img/f81c8448-47cb-4448-b1d3-d59a07394bb4.jpg?w=500`

Azure's Blob store doesn't know what to do with `?w=500`. Your URLs in your HTML pages should *never* point to `blob.core.windows.net`; they should point to your *server*  - or, a CDN *that points to your server* (not the blobstore!).

Comment: can you point me to some more specific info about how to properly setup the blob store urls?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but nonetheless as Nathanael's answer says the image URL should be:

`http://myserverwithimageresizer.com/img/img/f81c8448-47cb-4448-b1d3-d59a07394bb4.jpg?w=500`

Or for example if you are running locally :

```
http://localhost:<PORT>/img/img/f81c8448-47cb-4448-b1d3-d59a07394bb4.jpg?width=200
```

To use image resizer you should point to your website then set the reference to blob storage in your web.config file. If it directly access blob storage the image won't have a chance to be resized.

To set the prefix to nothing in web config put the following:

```
<add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=my;AccountKey=my endpoint="http://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/" />
```

By default the prefix is "~/azure" to set it to nothing it should be "~/"

This should make it so if you navigate to
`http://myserverwithimageresizer.com/img/f81c8448-47cb-4448-b1d3-d59a07394bb4.jpg?w=500` that your image is retrieved from blob storage and resized.